# Understanding datum and elevation of NASA ASTER DTM?

Tags: dem, elevation, datum, aster

I have downloaded some data from http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

I would like to relate the elevations to some coastal data which is estimated to a specific ordnance dataum.

Can anyone tell me what the datum (i.e. 0) refers to in ASTER data?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one-line answer for you: in this [Aster User Guide](http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/content/03_data/04_Documents/aster_user_guide_v2.pdf) on page 55 the Datum for all ASTER data processed at GDS is WGS84.

Another one liner:  [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25850/elevation-correction-aster-gdem2-10m?rq=1) has plenty of datum discussion.